# Font problem with txfonts

Tags: math-mode, fonts, symbols

This MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{txfonts}

\def\ket#1{\left\lvert#1\right\rangle}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \ket{\psi_{0,A}}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

produces a nice output with the `\lvert` and the `\rangle` having the same height.

But if I uncomment `\usepackage{txfonts}`, I get the `\lvert` higher than the `\rangle`.

What happens?

Answer (score 3):

Well, you found another of the several reasons for not using `txfonts`. It was a good attempt at getting Times compatible math symbols, but it's plagued with a lot of inconsistencies and bad kernings.

Use NewTX instead.

However you should use neither `\def` nor `\left` and `\right`. See the manual of `mathtools` for `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}% also loads amsmath

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ket{\lvert}{\rangle}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \ket{\psi_{0,A}} + \ket*{\frac{\psi_{0,A}}{2}}
\end{equation*}

Now compare $\ket{\psi_{j}}$ with $\left\lvert\psi_{j}\right\rangle$

\end{document}
```

[image]

I added the second part to show why you should not use `\left` and `\right` by default: you see that in the second version (equivalent to your definition) the delimiters are oversized for no reason.

Comment: Thanks, that's the solution that I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Using `\def\ket#1{\lvert\,#1\,\rangle}` instead of `\def\ket#1{\left\lvert#1\right\rangle}` there is not problem. You will not have `\lvert` higher than the `\rangle`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{txfonts}

\def\ket#1{\lvert\,#1\,\rangle}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \ket{\psi_{0,A}}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem is that without ```\left``` and ```\right```, the symbols do not scale.